# Is there a django admin widget that allows the admin to sort model objects by fields values?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-import-export

I am building an app in Django.

I found there is a very easy way to integrate a widget into django admin that allows the admin to filter model objects by fields values. That is achieved by including the line

```
list_filter = ['field_to_filter_by_its_values']
```

into the `class mymodelAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin)` in `admin.py`, as shown below

```
class target_area_history_dataAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = target_area_history_dataResource

    list_filter = ['Target_area_input_data__Name']

admin.site.register(target_area_history_data, target_area_history_dataAdmin)
```

[image]

Now, instead of integrate a widget to **filter** my model objects by that field, is there a way to integrate a widget to **sort** my model objects by that field?

**Note:** I am using Django Import-Export in my model.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using the grapelli admin interface that allows what you need and a bit more. here you have the [grapelli project page](https://grappelliproject.com/) and the https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli.

It's a well documented package and is plug and play for what you need. It also gives a fresh face to Django Admin and is compatible with Django import/export package.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest you use django-treebeard. This allows you to view tree nodes hierarchically in the administration interface, with interface features dependent upon the tree algorithm used.

```py
# admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from treebeard.admin import TreeAdmin


from .models import Category 


class CategoryAdmin(TreeAdmin):
    list_display = ("title", "created", "modified",)
    list_filter = ("created",)

 
admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
```

What's cool about this is that you can **not only sort (by clicking the header row)** but also drag things around, as shown in this image.

[image]